# Formatting an array of Javascript data

Tags: javascript

This code is for a web chat. I'm looking to have this code inspect each word, and then format only the twitter @joeblow username as twitter profile link.

Simply put, I'm parsing chat data to turn the text into twitter links, hashtags,a /command or just leave it as text if it's not any of these three. Below is my debug code.

I'm trying to learn how to use apply or call and don't completely understand them. As far as the code, it should take in the context array, and apply the format function to each item in the array.

Please note this is my first time trying to use apply() and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

When I run `format.apply(undefined,context('@joeblow is my username'));` it just returns `[twitter]@joeblow`. It should be printing something like `[twitter]@joeblow [default]is [default]my [default]username`. In a real world scenario, @joeblow would be HTML that links to @joeblows profile (the pseudo code below is just for brevity).

I want the format() function to apply to every word passed. The context() function just takes the passed in data and makes it into an array. I know I could write a for loop, but I'm trying to learn how to use apply()/call().

```
function preformat(message) {
  format_message = {
    '#': 'hashtag',
    '/': 'command',
    '@': 'twitter'
  }
  var char = message.charAt(0);
  var type = format_message[char];
  if (type) {
    return type;
  } else {
    return 'default';
  }
}

function context(input) {
  var message = [];
  var words = input.split(' ');
  for (var i=0;i<words.length;i++) {
    message[i] = words[i];
  }
  return message;
}

function format(message) {
  var type = preformat(message);
  format.types = {
    'command': function(type, message) { return '[command]' + message; },
    'hashtag': function(type, message) { return '[hashtag]' + message; },
    'twitter': function(type, message) { return '[twitter]' + message; },
    'default': function(type, message) { return '[default]' + message; }
  }
  var parse = format.types[type];
  return parse(type,message);
}
```

I'm executing this using:

```
format.apply(undefined,context('@joeblow is my username'));
```

Comment: You forgot to declare some variables with `var`, they are leaking to the global scope.

Comment: Well I'm still a little confused on what you are trying to accomplish but when is writing a for loop not a good way to do something that requires looping? I mean you can use map aswell...

Comment: @ScottMitchell I'm trying to learn how to use apply or call and don't completely understand them. As far as the code, it should take in the context array, and apply the format function to each item in the array. I'll update my description.

Comment: Well I dont see where you are using applyc/call in this example which is what is confusing. But the fundamental difference is that apply is an array of arguments whereas call is a list. They do the same thing.. Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, @ScottMitchell. I did read that, but I was reading the MDN example you gave and it was using objects for .call(); Edit: Okay, I see what you mean now. I was thinking call() was for strings....So I should definitely use apply(), but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. The last line of my code shows the line I'm using to execute this.

Comment: Think of it this way @ScottMitchell: User is typing their twitter name in chat. I'm looking to have this code inspect each word, and then format only the twitter \@joeblow username as twitter profile link.

Comment: Well, I got it working using Array.prototype.map(), based on @ScottMitchell's suggestion. I may post that as the answer unless one of you guys has a way to do this using apply();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're having is that whilst you're using `apply` to pass the split string to `format` as individual arguments, nowhere within that function do you actually iterate over those arguments.

`.apply` won't do that for you automatically - you *must* either use an explicit loop, or a function like `.map` that implicitly loops over an array.

The primary use for `.apply` is for invoking functions when you don't know in advance how many parameters you're going to pass to a function that expects separate parameters instead of an array.

Since your `format` function effectively only takes a single argument and returns the formatted version of that argument just try this, instead:

```
context("@joeblow is my username").map(format).join(' ');
```

Comment: Ah, okay. Thank you. I had figured out the solution using `map` minutes before you posted this but I'm accepting this as it answers my questions concerning `apply`.